# Returning a point (x,y) in a array if there is another point (p,q) such that x < p and y < q

Tags: java, arrays, recurrence

I am trying to make a recursive algorithm that uses divide and conquer on a set of 2-dimensional coordinates where (x,y) is valid if there is a (p,q) in the set where x < p and y < q.

I was thinking I could use a for loop to go through each coordinate in the array and would send the point I am looking for along with the array to a function that will split the array into smaller and smaller arrays until there is an array of size 1, then see if the point in the array is greater than the given point, and return/print the point if the conditions are correct.

The thing is, I just want to print the point once, not every time it finds a condition that is true. I am getting hung up on what to return so I just get the point to print.

I tried writing a simplier code in Java just to print if a single integer is less than another integer:

```java
package ComS311HW3;

public class Test2 {
    static int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    static void isLessThan(int num, int arr[]) {
        if(arr.length == 1) {
            if(num < arr[0])
                System.out.println(num);
        }
        else {
         int n = arr.length;
            int arrA[] = new int[(n+1)/2];
            int arrB[] = new int[n-arrA.length];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arrA, 0, arrA.length);
            System.arraycopy(arr, arrA.length, arrB, 0, arrB.length);
            isLessThan(num,arrA);
            isLessThan(num,arrB);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            isLessThan(arr[i], arr);
            }
    }
}
```

Looking at some other code, and implementing a points class, I did this and it worked:

```
package ComS311HW3;
```

public class Test2 {
    static int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

```
static points isLessThan(points point, points arr[], int left, int right) {
    if(right < left)
        return null;
    if(point.getX() < arr[left].getX() && point.getY() < arr[left].getY() )
        return point;
    if(point.getX() < arr[right].getX() && point.getY() < arr[right].getY() )
        return point;
    return isLessThan(point, arr, left +1, right -1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    points arr[] = new points[10];

    arr[0]= new points(1,2);
    arr[1]= new points(10,20);
    arr[2]= new points(2,4);
    arr[3]= new points(5,6);
    arr[4]= new points(7,4);
    arr[5]= new points(3,4);
    arr[6]= new points(8,9);
    arr[7]= new points(4,4);
    arr[8]= new points(2,3);
    arr[9]= new points(20,1);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        points temp = isLessThan(arr[i], arr, 0, arr.length-1);
        if(temp != null)
            System.out.println("(" + arr[i].getX() + "," + arr[i].getY() + ") is a valid point");
    }
}
```

}

But only did a recursion, still not sure how to divide this

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: Find the max of the set. If the target exceeds max, it doesn't matter what's in the rest of the set

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  But I have not done exhaustive testing.  I generate the test points using the Random class.

```
Random r = new Random();
Point[] pts = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(
                a -> new Point(r.nextInt(20), r.nextInt(30)))
        .toArray(Point[]::new);

// show the points
for (Point pt : pts) {
    System.out.println(pt);
}

System.out.println("Searching");
Point p = findPoint(pts, new Point(10, 20));
System.out.println("Returned");
System.out.println(p == null ? "Not found" : p);

public static Point findPoint(Point[] pts, Point target) {
    if (pts.length == 1) {
        Point p = pts[0];
        if (p.x < target.x && p.y < target.y) {
            return p;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    int mid = pts.length / 2;
    Point[] a1 = new Point[mid];
    Point[] a2 = new Point[pts.length - mid];
    System.arraycopy(pts, 0, a1, 0, a1.length);
    Point p = findPoint(a1, target);
    if (p != null) {
        return p;
    }
    System.arraycopy(pts, mid, a2, 0, a2.length);
    return findPoint(a2, target);

}
```

Prints

```
java.awt.Point[x=17,y=2]
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=14]
java.awt.Point[x=5,y=26]
java.awt.Point[x=8,y=14]
java.awt.Point[x=7,y=20]
java.awt.Point[x=4,y=8]
java.awt.Point[x=15,y=24]
java.awt.Point[x=9,y=14]
java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
java.awt.Point[x=10,y=19]
Searching
Returned
java.awt.Point[x=2,y=14]
```

Comment: Okay, but I need to do this using divide and conquer, so something like halving the points array and then comparing the point.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see the recursion now, I think

Comment: If you position some print statements at key locations you can witness the arrays decreasing in size as the method is recursively called.

Comment: The thing is, the program is supposed to print out any points, not just look for a specific point. It's supposed to be checking all the points in the array of points and printing out the point if there is another point with an x and y that is higher. If arr[0] is (1,2) and at a[n] it is (2,3) then (1,2) would be returned as valid.

Comment: You said, *The thing is, I just want to print the point once, not every time it finds a condition that is true. I am getting hung up on what to return so I just get the point to print.*  So I only printed when the condition was true once which is what you said.  Not every time the comparison evaluated to true.